# CloudKit subscriptions in tvOS

Tags: swift, cloudkit, tvos

I am trying to sync data between a few Apple TVs using CloudKit and CKSubcription. The problem is `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` is never called when I add, delete, or update records. I believe I am configuring the subscriptions correctly and I have confirmed they are added to the CloudKit dashboard. I have repeatedly tried resetting the development environment in the dashboard, but that is not helping. I really don't want to create a timer to fetch every so often. Thanks for any help!

Also, I am using the private database in CloudKit and not the public database if that matters.

Here's my code:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    CloudKitManager.subscribeToItemUpdates()
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    ...

    return true
}
```

**CloudKitManager.swift**

```
class func subscribeToItemUpdates() {

    if let uuid = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor?.UUIDString {

        saveSubscriptionWithIdentifier(uuid + "create", options: CKSubscriptionOptions.FiresOnRecordCreation)
        saveSubscriptionWithIdentifier(uuid + "update", options: CKSubscriptionOptions.FiresOnRecordUpdate)
        saveSubscriptionWithIdentifier(uuid + "delete", options: CKSubscriptionOptions.FiresOnRecordDeletion)
    }

}

class func saveSubscriptionWithIdentifier(identifier: String, options: CKSubscriptionOptions) {

    let sub = CKSubscription(recordType: "Message", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), subscriptionID: identifier, options: options)
    sub.notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()

    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        publicDatabase.saveSubscription(sub) { (savedSubscription, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error saving CloudKit subscription \(error)")
        }
        else {
            print("Saved subscription to CloudKit", savedSubscription)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight difference between tvOS and iOS. In my demo app i handle it like this:

```
#if os(tvOS)
//This will only be called when your app is active. So this is what you should use on tvOS
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    EVLog("Push received")
    EVCloudData.publicDB.didReceiveRemoteNotification(userInfo, executeIfNonQuery: {
        EVLog("Not a CloudKit Query notification.")
    }, completed: {
        EVLog("All notifications are processed")
    })
}
#else
// Process al notifications even if we are in the background. tvOS will not have this event
// Make sure you enable background notifications in the app settings. (entitlements: pushnotifications and  backgrounds modes - notifications plus background fetch)
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    EVLog("Push received")
    EVCloudData.publicDB.didReceiveRemoteNotification(userInfo, executeIfNonQuery: {
        EVLog("Not a CloudKit Query notification.")
    }, completed: {
        EVLog("All notifications are processed")
        completionHandler(.NewData)
    })
}
#endif
```

For more information see [EVCloudKitDao](https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao/blob/f54cd4705542eb00b10252ea4233a74872a8e491/AppMessage/AppMessage/AppDelegate.swift#L46-L46)

Comment: I am using `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification` and not `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler`. I looked at EVCloudKitDao and it seems you are deleting all subscriptions and resubscribing every time the app launches. I am not doing that, is that possibly the issue? Is it necessary? Does it make a difference since I am using the private database and not the public database in CloudKit? Thanks